# InvalidArgumentError in while_loop with sparse tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using a while_loop to iteratively update a matrix. The loop runs fine with dense tensors, but when I use sparse tensors I get the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Number of rows of a_indices does not match
>   number of entries in a_values      [[Node:
>   while/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul =
>   SparseTensorDenseMatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, Tindices=DT_INT64,
>   adjoint_a=false, adjoint_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](while/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/Enter,
>   while/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/Enter_1,
>   ConstantFolding/dense_to_sparse/Shape_enter/_1, while/Switch_1:1)]]
>   [[Node: while/Exit_1/_5 = _Recvclient_terminated=false,
>   recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_62_while/Exit_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

The only thing that I change between the two versions is to convert HH with HH=tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse(HH) and use tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(HH,f) instead of tf.matmul(HH,f) - shown in the commented code below.

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    g=tf.constant(g,shape=[np.size(g),1],dtype=tf.float32)
    H=tf.constant(H,dtype=tf.float32);
    Ht=tf.transpose(H)
    HH=tf.matmul(Ht,H)
    #HH=tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse(HH)
    a=tf.matmul(Ht,g)
    i=tf.constant(0,dtype=tf.int32)
    f=tf.constant(f,dtype=tf.float32)
    body = lambda i,f:(tf.add(i,1),tf.divide(tf.multiply(f,a),tf.matmul(HH,f)+10e-9))
    #body = lambda i,f:(tf.add(i,1),tf.divide(tf.multiply(f,a),tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(HH,f)+10e-9))
    cond= lambda i,f:tf.less(i,iterations)
    i,f=tf.while_loop(cond,body,(i,f))
sess=tf.Session()
i,f=sess.run([i,f])
```

Note that this code does work as long as H, g and f are small enough. For example, this error occurs for H.shape=(8000,3840) ,g.shape=(8000,1), f.shape=(3840,1) and larger , but works fine for H.shape=(8000,3584) ,g.shape=(8000,1), f.shape=(3584,1) and smaller . Do I need to do something special for sparse tensors in while loops to ensure they maintain their shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried updating from tensorflow 1.8 to 1.12 and tensorflow stopped working altogether (ts.Session would hang indefinitely). So, I nuked my anaconda environment and started from scratch with tensorflow 1.12.  After this update/re-install, the problem with sparse tensors went away, though it is unclear if the issue was with the version of tensorflow or something else in my anaconda environment.